# Is it possible to get pages from a list using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

I have a Facebook list that just contains a selection of pages that I have liked. I have permissions for 'user_likes' and 'read_friendlists', but it seems that only friends on a list are returned and not any pages on the list. Is there another permission I need or is it not possible to get pages from a list through the Facebook Graph API? I am having no problem getting a list of all my likes or all my friends on a list, but I don't want a list of all my likes, just those on my list.

For my list that just contains pages I get no results in the Facebook Graph API Explorer when I go to this URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/MY-LIST-ID/members